# Receiving extra chars when sending message queue for POSIX

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I've pretty much completed a simple forking program where one process sends an array of chars to its parent process by using mq_send and mq_receive, and outputs the reversed string.  However, for some reason when I sometimes input a string to be sent, the receiving end of the program has added on characters to it. What's more is that this seems random, as sending the same string again will give the proper output.

Here is the entire code, and an example output after.

```
#include  <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include  <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <unistd.h> /* get_pid */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit, EXIT_FAILURE */
#include <sys/wait.h>   /* wait */
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 500

void reverse(char s[]);
void clientFunction(const char *msgqname);
void serverFunction(const char *msgqname);
int main(void)
{
    //A
    char msgQName[] = "/queue";
    //B
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){      
        clientFunction(msgQName);
    }
    else {
        usleep(10L);
        serverFunction(msgQName);
    }
    return(0);

}
void clientFunction(const char *msgqname){
    //C

    mqd_t mqident = mq_open(msgqname, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT ,  0666, NULL);
    //D
    if (mqident == -1){
        printf("Error opening message queue. Exiting program. \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    char str[MAX_STR_LEN];  //Keep the string that has been read from input and written on the pipe
    memset(str,0,strlen(str));  
    while(1){

        printf("Enter an string:");
        gets(str);  //Reads the string from input
        printf("%i\n",strlen(str));
        unsigned len = (unsigned) strlen(str); //Finds the length of the string
        int sent = mq_send(mqident,str,len,0);
        if (sent == -1){
            printf("Error sending message. Exiting program. \n");
            exit (0);
        }
        usleep(10L);
        memset(str,0,strlen(str));
    }

}
void serverFunction(const char *msgqname){
    //F
    mqd_t mqident = mq_open (msgqname,O_RDONLY|O_CREAT , 0666, NULL);

    if (mqident == -1){
        printf("Error opening message queue. Exiting program. \n");
        printf( "Error : %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit(0);
    }
    char str1[MAX_STR_LEN];
    memset(str1,0,strlen(str1));
    struct mq_attr attr;
    while(1){
        //G
        mq_getattr(mqident,&attr);
        //H
        ssize_t receive = mq_receive(mqident,str1,attr.mq_msgsize,0);
        if (receive == -1){
            printf("Error receiving message. Exiting program. \n");
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("%i, %i\n",strlen(str1), attr.mq_msgsize);
        reverse(str1);
        printf("What you wrote in reverse was:%s\n", str1); 
        memset(str1,0,strlen(str1));
    }

}
void reverse(char s[])
{
      int length = strlen(s) ;
      int c, i, j;

      for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
     {
     c = s[i];
     s[i] = s[j];
     s[j] = c;
      }
}
```

Example output, when compiled with gcc with -o and -lrt in terminal

```
Enter an string:tester 1234567890     
17
21
What you wrote in reverse was:1��0987654321 retset
Enter an string:tester 1234567890
17
17
What you wrote in reverse was:0987654321 retset
Enter an string:
```

The two integer values in the output are what I used to check the lengths, the first one is the strlen of the sending string and the 2nd is the strlen of the receiving string.

I made sure to empty the strings right after initialization and printf, so I don't know where these mystery characters are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *void serverfunction()* and *void clientFunction()*

Replace `memset(str1,0,strlen(str1))`.

with     `memset(str1,0,sizeof(str1))`.

`sizeof` will give the total sizeof the array

Now probably you will not get junk data.

Comment: @user2844080 my side above correction working proper. which OS and compiler you using

Comment: @user2844080 replace all the memset with `sizeof`.

Comment: Changing all of them seemed to have fixed the problem, thanks alot! I'm guessing the reason it didn't change the first time was due to not changing the strlen part in the send function?

Comment: @user2844080 accept the answer as correct, if it helped for you.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the first time there seem to be four more characters received than those sent.
The reason is that the string `str1` is not NULL terminated, because of
the `memset` which initializes the character array `str1`.
Try changing it to:

```
memset(str1, 0, MAX_STR_LEN);
```

and your program should work as expected.

---

On second thought, you shouldn't need the `memset` at all, if you were sending your string properly.  Your `gets` will append a `'\0'` at the end of your `str`.  But `len(str)` will not count that.  This means that you'll just send the real characters, not the final `'\0'`.

There are two better ways to fix your problem, therefore:

1. The other side appends the final `'\0'`, upon receiving the string.  You can do this by adding the line:

   ```
   str1[receive] = '\0';
   ```

   just after your `mq_receive`.
2. The final `'\0'` is sent as well.  You can do this by sending `len+1` characters in your `mq_send`.

With both fixes, you can get rid of both `memset` calls in your code.